# how to solve attribute error when all attributes do exist?

Tags: python, inheritance, attributeerror

I am writing a program for my A level course in python and i need to access an attribute from one class in to another using inheritance. here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.testValue = 'hello'

class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inheritedValue = class1.testValue
        print(self.inheritedValue)



object = class2()
```

when running this code i get the following attribute error.

AttributeError: type object 'class1' has no attribute 'testValue'

anyone got a solution for this??

Comment: `class1` *doesn't* have an attribute named `testValue`. *Instances* of that class do.

Comment: thank you, how would i be able to get testValue in class2?

Comment: There are *lots* of ways, but which one you want depends on what you are actually trying to model. Should `testValue` be a class attribute of `class1`, or `class2`, just a parameter to `class2.__init__`, or even (possibly) a module global variable? It could even just be a hard-coded value in the definition of `__init__`. It's impossible to pick one "correct" method given the limited information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

First a comment to code style: class names are written in CamelCase, so name them Class1 and Class2.

Secondly, your *class* Class1 doesn't have the said attribute, but each instance does.

So your class2 should look like

```
class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # now we have everything Class1 provides us with
        self.inheritedValue = self.testValue
        print(self.inheritedValue)
```

because each object of Class2 is also an object of Class1

Comment: Class names are written in different ways depending on the direction of the wind and phase of the moon.  See `list`.

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for strange coding style i just wrote this code up quickly to produce the same error i am having in my main project as i didn't want to post large amounts of code, cheers again!!

Comment: @JohnZwinck I was referring to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which AFAIK is in widespread use.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute does not exist within the scope of `class2` the way you've implemented it. By passing it in the class definition, it is inherited but the attribute doesn't exist yet. That is, unless you've called the constructor. Two ways of doing this, by either using the `super` built-in function(not recommended in real life, see [here](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/), it's a nice read. Anyway, here are a few solutions:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.testValue = 'hello'

class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self):
        class1.__init__(self)        
        print(self.testValue)



obj = class2()
```

if you do not want to call the constructor of the class you are inheriting, you could do something like this:

```
class class1():
    testValue = 'hello'
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inheritedValue = class1.testValue
        print(self.inheritedValue)

obj = class2()
```

Side note, `object` is a built-in so you shouldn't use it.